# Solving$ x(x-1)\ddot y-x\dot y+y=x(x-1)^2$ by using integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving $x(x-1)\ddot y-x\dot y+y=x(x-1)^2$ given the solution $y_1=x$

I set $y=vx$, have plugged and rearranged. I set my integrating factor to:

$$e^\left({\int\frac{x-2}{x(x-1)}dx}\right)$$

Multiplying both sides by it, and after setting $z=\dot v$ I have:

$$\frac{x^2}{x-1}\dot z +\frac{x(x-2)}{(x-1)^2} z = x$$

I know now this is a separable D.E., but it seems I'm unable to separate. A hint in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_1=x$ is NOT solution of the original ODE :$\quad x(x-1)\ddot y-x\dot y+y=x(x-1)^2$

$y_1=x$ is solution of the associated homogeneous ODE :$\quad x(x-1)\ddot y-x\dot y+y=0$

OK. for the change of function : $y=vx$

$x(x-1)(x \ddot v+2 \dot v )-x(x \dot v +v)+vx=x(x-1)^2$

$$x(x-1) \ddot v +(x-2) \dot v =(x-1)^2$$

$$z=\dot v \quad\to\quad x(x-1) \dot z +(x-2) z =(x-1)^2$$

This is consistent with the equation that you found : $\frac{x^2}{x-1}\dot z +\frac{x(x-2)}{(x-1)^2} z = x$

You cannot "separate" it because it is a non-homogeneous ODE.

First, you have to solve the associated homogeneous ODE :
$$x(x-1) \dot z +(x-2) z =0$$
I suppose that you know how to proceed, either with the separation of variables method, or using an integrating factor.

Then, you will have to add a particular solution of $\frac{x^2}{x-1}\dot z +\frac{x(x-2)}{(x-1)^2} z = x $ in order to have the general solution. For example, use the method of variation of parameter to find a particular solution.